# Keep NoData values when using gdal_merge

Tags: gdal, javascript, nodata, gdal-merge

I'm using gdal_merge to join several BioClim rasters, which I will then feed into a Java program that "snaps" points to the nearest BioClim raster tile of non-NoData value. However, when I run gdal_merge, it assigns the NoData value of the BioClim file (`NoData Value=-3.39999999999999996e+38`) to each of the tiles as if it's a proper value (I think).

Running gdal_info on the merged raster shows that value as the minimum, with no indication of a NoData value; whereas running gdal_info on one of the pre-merged raster tiles shows it assigned to the NoData values.

I think this is creating an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error when I then run the Java program... preventing me from snapping the points successfully.

I have two questions:

1) How do I use gdal_merge such that the NoData classification of cells are preserved in the merged output?

2) Could something else be causing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? I'm a novice with Java programs.

Comment: Did you try to assign nodata value http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html?

Comment: I did, but the gdalinfo statistics indicate the values have not been maintained correctly (e.g., `statistics_minimum` is now the original NoData value).

Comment: I would try http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html next. If that fails you should make a test package with data and actual complete commands.

Answer (score 3):

In order to maintain *NoData* cells in the output you seem to need to use both the "-n" option (specifying the *NoData* value for the input) and the "-a_nodata" option (specifying the *NoData* value for the output).  For example:

`gdal_merge.py -n -9999 -a_nodata -9999 -o merged.tif in*.tif`

My version of *gdal_merge* does not overwrite existing files (it just touches them), so I have to remove "merged.tif" before running the command.